# regular expression to find lines containing multiple specific words or patterns in any arbitrary order

Tags: regular-expression

Suppose we have the following very simple file:

```
1 x 3 x
x 3 x 1
```

Now I'd like to have a pattern that matches all lines containing *both* `1` and `3`. The order and position should not matter.

(Note that I used a very simple file on purpose. The file could contain many more lines, and the ”words“ could be words like ”hello“ and ”world“.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way is to use [:h /\&](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%26) , it works a bit like `&&` in most coding language:

```
pattern0\&pattern1
```

Above expression will match pattern1 if pattern0 also match at the same position.

To solve your example:

```
\v^(.*1&.*3).*$
```

- `\v` very magic
- `^` start of line
- `(.*1&.*3)` match `.*3` if `.*1` matches.
- `.*$` match anything until line end

If you have multiple patterns, you can write it as:

```
\v^(.*pattern0&.*pattern1&.*pattern2...).*$
```

Comment: I've never really understood what `/\&` is for. Now I do. Which is weird, because this is essentially identical to the "Peter and Bob" example given in the `:help`. Still, reading your answer, it finally clicked in my brain. Thanks! +1

Comment: This is way easier to type in general, and I (like Rich) learned something. +1; this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: `it works a bit like && in most coding language:` is brilliant!

Answer (score 4):

Here's another alternative: use [`:h /bar`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2Fbar) to match either *…1…3…* or *…3…1…*:

```
\v.*(1.*3|3.*1).*
```

- `\v` very magic
- `.*` anything (or nothing)
- `(...)` a group, containing either:

  - `1.*3` `1` followed by anything followed by `3`
  - `|` or
  - `3.*1` `3` followed by anything followed by `1`
- `.*` anything

Comment: nicely explained, therefore +1

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use a pattern with multiple lookaheads:

```
magic:        ^\(.*1\)\@=\(.*3\)\@=
                   ‾         ‾

very magic:   \v^(.*1)@=(.*3)@=
                    ‾      ‾
```

Since lookaheads (and lookarounds in general) do not consume characters, the same line can be searched for multiple different patterns/words.

---

**additional hint:**

This even allows one to add another condition to the regular expression: matching lines that contain `1` and `3`, but do *not* contain `x`:

```
magic:        ^\(.*1\)\@=\(.*3\)\@=\(.*x\)\@!
                   ‾         ‾         ‾

very magic:   \v^(.*1)@=(.*3)@=(.*x)@!
                    ‾      ‾      ‾
```

Comment: I'd consider removing the `\<`, `\>`, `<`, and `>` end-of-word atoms from this answer. They're not required for the simple example given in your question, and your regular expressions are easier to understand without them!

Comment: thank you @Rich for your edit and your suggestion!